# Add custom column to Entry Type index page

Tags: plugin-development, entry-type, hook

I'm creating a plugin and I've been following the Mijingo Craft plugin development videos. I reached the point where a column was added to the entry index page. I was looking to do something similar but on the Entry type index page `/admin/settings/sections/{ID}/entrytypes`.

I was unable to find anything in the documentation (maybe I missed something). But is there a method I can use to do this? or is it not possible?

Comment: I'm curious about the use case here. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @MatsMikkelRummelhoff I'm counting the number of entries that use a specific entry type. clients have come to me several times asking for this. thought it'd be neat to see the entry count on entry type index page

Comment: Honestly, I'd advice against giving clients admin access (which you'd need to see the entry type index) unless they absolutely need it. That being said, considering the fact that what you want to do isn't possible without hacking core files – how about a writing a plugin which adds a custom [CP section](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/templates#giving-your-plugin-its-own-cp-section) instead? That CP section could contain the stats you want to expose to your client, and would even be available from the main menu.

Comment: @MatsMikkelRummelhoff I've created the CP section and widget that displays these stats already :)

Comment: Alright, good call. Regarding the entry type index – no offence, but I personally wouldn't want my clients messing about inside Settings just to view some stats (even if they are tech savvy). The CP section and widget sounds like a good solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not possible currently.

If you feel that [a hook](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference) for customizing the Entry Type listing/index should exist, you can [add a feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to see your custom field in under the Entries index page of the Section.

This is what I know from Craft CMS ver. 2.5 or 2.6

On the Entries index page of the Section, click on the settings icon found on the left side bar, ensure you are on the section to show/hide the columns.

Hope this is useful for you.

Comment: That feature is available in the element indexes (i.e. `/admin/entries/news`). The OP is specifically asking about the entry types index inside the settings (i.e. `/admin/settings/sections/2/entrytypes`.